# PayPal REST API Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal

Does anybody knows when this feature will be supported by REST API? I'm really like PayPal REST API, but this feature is very important to me and I believe to many other developers

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't officially speak for PayPal, since I have not worked for them in over a year (and wasn't an official spokesperson then either). However, since they almost certainly won't give you an official answer let me say what I can to help you:

Adaptive Payments (AP) is a product line, not a feature. AP is a bundle of features and behaviors, with an interface designed almost 10 years ago now (before the world converged on REST-style APIs).

PayPal's REST APIs, while named after an interface technology, are in fact also a product line, not a feature. A different product line from AP, with a different set of behaviors and features.

So AP being supported by PayPal's REST APIs is like saying "when will the Chevy Tahoe be supported by the Chevy Equinox"? Wrong question.

However there are two things that PayPal could actually do:

1) update AP with REST-adherent versions of the existing AP APIs. These would not be PayPal's REST API product, but the AP APIs reskinned. However, IMO the chances of this are near-zero for a variety of reasons. Don't hold your breath (or your development) hoping for this.

2) Improve the REST APIs by adding more features that AP currently has but the REST APIs do not. This is quite likely to happen, as part of the incremental improvement of the REST APIs, which PayPal wants to use as one of their primary going-forward integration paths (secondary in importance only to Braintree-based integration paths, if any).

If you can enumerate the specific features of AP that you want to see added to the REST APIs, let PayPal know. They likely won't promise dates for future feature deliveries (unless you are a strategic partner contracting with them to get those additions), but they are definitely actively working through a roadmap of REST improvements.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.